Inconsistency between Jones vectors and Stokes parameters
Plane wave equation :
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(z,t)=\left| \begin{array}{c}
E_{0}^{x}e^{i\delta_{x}} \\
E_{0}^{y}e^{i\delta_{y}} \\
0 \\
\end{array}\right|e^{i(\omega t -kz)}\quad,\quad E_0^{x,y}
\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
which can be rewritten at $z=0$ and changing the time origin :
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(0,t)=\left| \begin{array}{c}
E_{0}^{x} \\
E_{0}^{y}e^{i\delta} \\
0 \\
\end{array}\right|e^{i(\omega t)}\quad,\quad E_0^{x,y}
\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
with $\delta = \delta_y - \delta_x \in [0,2\pi [$.
The $z$ axis is in the direction of the Poynting vector of the plane wave (same direction as $\vec{k}$), as on following picture.

The Jones vectors are a representation of degenerate light polarization states :

horizontal : the $x$ axis, in the sequel $E_H = E_x$
\begin{equation}
  | H \rangle = (1,0)^T
  \end{equation}

vertical : the $y$ axis, in the sequel $E_V = E_y$
\begin{equation}
  | V \rangle = (0,1)^T
  \end{equation}

left circular (clockwise)
\begin{equation}
  | L \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1,i)^T    \qquad                    (1)
  \end{equation}

right circular (counter clockwise)
\begin{equation}
  | R \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1,-i)^T         \qquad               (2)   
  \end{equation}


For left and right circular polarizations, I follow the convention of increasing phase ($\omega t - kz$) with time.
That is to note horizontal and vertical polarizations can be expressed with left and right circular polarizations :
\begin{equation}
|H\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|R\rangle + |L\rangle)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
|V\rangle = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} (|R\rangle - |L\rangle)
\end{equation}
In latter equation, the phase factor $i$ could be omitted, but I prefer to keep it, otherwise there is no more consistency between Jones vectors.
With $E_H$ and $E_V$, one can derive Stokes parameters :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S_{0} &= (E_{0}^{H})^{2} + (E_{0}^{V})^{2} \newline
S_{1} &= (E_{0}^{H})^{2} - (E_{0}^{V})^{2} \newline
S_{2} &= 2E_{0}^{H}E_{0}^{V}\cos(\delta) \newline
S_{3} &= 2E_{0}^{H}E_{0}^{V}\sin(\delta)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and $\delta = \delta_y - \delta_x = \delta_V - \delta_H $
For circular polarizations, I consider $E_0^x = E_0^y = \frac{E_0}{\sqrt{2}}$, where $(E_0)^2$ can be interpreted as the total light intensity.
Left circular polarization is characterized by $\delta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and right one by $\delta = - \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, for left circular polarization, $S_3 = (E_0)^2$ and for right circular polarization, $S_3 = - (E_0)^2$. This explains the position of left and right circular polarizations one the Poincaré sphere.

But $S_3$ can also be expressed as :
\begin{equation}
 S_3 = i(E_{H}E_{V}^{\star}- E_{H}^{\star}E_{V})
\end{equation}
If I replace $E_H$ and $E_V$ by their decomposition (Eqs. 1 and 2) in the $(E_L, E_R)$ basis (I implicitely identify the complex electric field $E$ with Jones vectors), one get :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S_3 &=i(E_{H}E_{V}^{\star}- E_{H}^{\star}E_{V})\newline
&= \frac{i}{2}[(E_R + E_L)(-i)(E_R^\star - E_L^\star)] - (E_R^\star + E_L^\star)(i)(E_R - E_L)]\newline
&=\frac{1}{2}[(E_R + E_L)(E_R^\star - E_L^\star)] + (E_R^\star + E_L^\star)(E_R - E_L)]\newline
&=|E_R|^2 - |E_L|^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, this would mean that $S_3= (E_0)^2$ for right circular polarization and $S_3 = - (E_0)^2$ for left one, which contradicts the previous results and the mapping on the Poincaré sphere !
I must be missing something, where is my error ?

the question seem pretty complete, but why do $E_x$, $E_y$ even show up? They just appear...maybe start with the plane wave whence the came? That could also be used to introduce $\delta_{(x, y, H, V}}$, which aren't defined in equations. But why even both with (x, y), and write the plane wave on  $E_H\hat x$, $E_V\hat y$ ...it would be clearer.

I updated my question by adding the definition of the plane wave and the fact that I identify horizontal polarization with $x$-axis and vertical with $y$ axis. It should be clearer now.

In your 2nd Eq. you seem to be meaing $\vec{E}(0,t)$ instead of $\vec{E}(z,t),$ because how it's written now, it has a $z$-dependent LHS while the RHS is $z$-independent.

Yes, I corrected this. The position on the $z$-axis is arbitrary. Both LHS and RHS are independent of the position on $z$-axis, it does not change computations.

So you have $E_{(x, y)}$ real, and $E_{(H, V)} = E_{(x, y)}$, and then are taking complex conjugates of $E_{(H, V)}$...what am I missing?

As you explain, your definitions for $|H\rangle, |V\rangle, |R\rangle$ and $|L\rangle$ are related by:
$$ \begin{align}
|H\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|R\rangle + |L\rangle)
\\
|V\rangle &= \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} (|R\rangle - |L\rangle)   \tag{1}
\end{align} $$
But that means that for the coefficients used with these basis vectors you have:
$$ \begin{align}
E_H &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (E_R + E_L)
\\
E_V &= \frac{1}{i\sqrt{2}} (E_R - E_L) \quad
\color{red}{\bf \Leftarrow\text{!!}}  \tag{2}
\end{align} $$
where the second line has $1/i$ instead of the factor $i$ in $(1)$. (If the basis has covariant vectors then the coefficients are contravariant! Or you could call it the difference between an active and a passive transformation.) You forgot to use that in evaluating your second definition of $S_3$ (below the 2nd image) where you erroneously use $E_V=\tfrac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(E_R - E_L)$.
To see that $(1)$ really leads to $(2)$ with the surprising $1/i$ factor, just solve for:
$$
  E = E_H \binom{1}{0}+E_V \binom{0}{1} = 
  E_L\ \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \binom{1}{i}+E_R\ \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \binom{1}{-i}
$$
which will unambiguously give you $E_H$ and $E_V$ expressed in $E_R$ and $E_L$

My bad ! yes I confounded decomposition vectors and their associated coefficients, all is right now. Thanks for point out this to me !
